# What causes RANK to show only odd numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query that is pulling a historical list of invoice statements. I am using RANK() OVER PARTITION on the statement date. The result set only show ODD numbers (1, 3, 5, 7 etc), Does anyone knows a reason why it is skipping the even numbers?

```
select Distinct  
TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.ivo_int_id
,TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.vst_int_id
,TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.step_action_dt
,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.vst_int_id ORDER BY TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.step_action_dt) as 'RankNo'

from TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY
join TSM603_EVENT_ACTION on TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.path_int_id = TSM603_EVENT_ACTION.path_int_id

WHERE TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.vst_int_id = 4564791
```

Here is a sample of the TPB805 file:

```
stmt_tag_hist_int_id    ivo_int_id  tickler_int_id  pat_nte_int_id  vst_int_id  path_int_id ar_letter_int_id    stmt_path_ctrl_int_id   stmt_path_tag_int_id    stmt_ctl_hist_int_id    row_sta_cd  lst_mod_id  lst_mod_ts  step_action_dt  interval_next_step  step_seq_no bad_debt_writeoff_fg    deny_ins_fg stmt_msg_int_id pymt_activity_msg_int_id    stmt_msg_txt_lint_1 stmt_msg_txt_lint_2 stmt_msg_txt_lint_3 stmt_msg_txt_lint_4 stmt_msg_txt_lint_5 stmt_msg_txt_lint_6 stmt_msg_txt_lint_7 stmt_msg_txt_lint_8 pymt_restart_seq    amt_due bgn_amt_due pymt_override_int_id    last_pmt_int_id last_chg_int_id bgn_pmt_int_id  bgn_chg_int_id  org_int_id  msg_ext_id  agent_int_id    guar_int_id new_chgs    new_pmts    guar_ext_id stmt_nbr    type_of_detail
5327    4600010 NULL    NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    32  A   SYSTEM                  25:27.4 00:00.0 30  1   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    327010.58   0   NULL    9530    223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3699062.67 NULL    0   D
51304   4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    276 A   SYSTEM                  21:54.5 26:01.6 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    327010.58   0   NULL    9530    223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3699062.67 NULL    0   D
102883  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    556 A   SYSTEM                  19:34.9 22:05.5 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    327010.58   0   NULL    9530    223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3699062.67 NULL    0   D
170303  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    863 A   SYSTEM                  28:10.8 19:40.3 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    271022.68   0   NULL    194530  223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3755050.57 NULL    0   D
241658  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    1172    A   SYSTEM                  25:53.3 28:15.8 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    271022.68   0   NULL    194530  223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3755050.57 NULL    0   D
308604  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    1482    A   SYSTEM                  30:52.2 25:56.5 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    271022.68   0   NULL    194530  223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3755050.57 NULL    0   D
430404  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    1992    A   SYSTEM                  47:19.8 30:57.6 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    65527.83    0   NULL    566188  223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3960545.42 NULL    0   D
508328  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    2317    A   SYSTEM                  24:25.4 47:23.4 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    65527.83    0   NULL    566188  223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3960545.42 NULL    0   D
581930  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    2683    A   SYSTEM                  31:40.6 24:28.8 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    65527.83    0   NULL    566188  223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3960545.42 NULL    0   D
648669  4600010 105 NULL    4564791 4   NULL    6   9969    3055    A   SYSTEM                  41:14.5 31:45.1 30  2   N   N   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    65527.83    0   NULL    566188  223163  0   0   388 NS-No Statement NULL    645531  4026073.25  -3960545.42 NULL    0   D
```

Here is data from the TSM603 table:

```
row_sta_cd  override_label  lst_mod_id  event_action_int_id path_time_int_id    path_int_id path_event_int_id   action_int_id   statement_sw    aging_days  lst_mod_ts  action_type bill_sw msg_override    default_msg msg_id  des_usr_int_id
A   ALL INS                 sziegler                10  18  4   4   4   1   0   41:59.5 3   NULL    NULL    NULL    6   NULL
A   Final Bill              sziegler                137 73  4   3   5   NULL    5   00:33.2 4   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

This is sample of the resulting list:

```
ivo_int_id  vst_int_id  step_action_dt  RankNo
4600010  4564791    2017-04-04 00:00     1
4600010  4564791    2017-05-11 00:26     3
4600010  4564791    2017-06-11 00:22     5
4600010  4564791    2017-07-12 00:19     7
4600010  4564791    2017-08-12 00:28     9
...
```

Comment: i think you have not put all output because RankNo=1 have to be 2 row like rank 1,1, then it may go to 3

Comment: I think you'll need to share some sample data from your two tables that leads to the result set you've shared here. I suspect, like @ZaynulAbadinTuhin that you've excluded some records from your result set before pasting here since this output doesn't make sense as-is. [You can see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a6c80d/1) that we can't replicate given the information you've posted so far

Comment: ***Order your results*** by the columns mentioned in your rank function, then you'll see that either there's a `2` further down the result set, or you have two `1`s.

Comment: @JNevill  I just added the corresponding data from the files to the OP

Comment: Add `ORDER BY TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.vst_int_i, TPB805_STMT_TAG_HISTORY.step_action_dt` to your query........

Comment: Adding the ORDER BY did not quite solve the problem by itself.  When I added the qualification "TSM603_EVENT_ACTION.action_type = 3 " to the WHERE statement, then the RANK works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Upon @JNevil's suggestion to share some of the data from the two files, I discover that there are 2 actions associated with each invoice statement: action 3 is for "Start Statement Process", action 4 is for "Start Insurance Notification".

When linking both tables, it created 2 output rows per invoice statement -- one row per action -- and because I was not pulling into the report the "action" into the result set and using DISTINCT it was only showing one row and skipping the other one.

When I added the qualification "TSM603_EVENT_ACTION.action_type = 3 " to the WHERE statement, then the RANK works as expected.

As long as I qualify on either one action, the RANK works as intended, otherwise it skips even numbers

Comment: Rank ***ONLY*** skips a number if two rows are tied.  You can get `1,1,3` or `1,2,3` but it is ***impossible*** to get `1,3,5`.  Your diagnostics are faulty, or the query you are running is not the query you have shown.